# how to use hx-53 (IR Transmitter Infrared Sensor Module) with ESP32?

Tags: esp32, ir

ESP32 tx2 (pin17) and rx2 (pin16) uses 3.3v based signals.

HX-53 data connect to tx2, gnd to gnd and vcc to vin(5v).

But as i can understand HX-53 data input should be 5v based.

How can i solve this problem?

HX-53: [https://www.amazon.com/Electronic-Infrared-Emission-Transmitter-Arduino/dp/B07PJC7WSQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PJC7WSQ)

Best regards.
GA

Comment: Either level shift chip or a voltage divider. Can you provide a link to the HX-53? Havent found it

Answer (score 3):

The HX-53 look like a IR LED and a current limiting resistor on a small PCB.

It also has a LED and a resistor in series for indication when the invisible IR diode is on or off.

So you can change the resistor to a lower value to match the 3,3 volt output from the ESP32.

Resistor values:

```
221 = 220 ohm   = IR LED
102 = 1000 ohm  = SMD indicator LED
```

So replace the 220 ohm with something near 75 ohm.

**HX-53**

[image]

Comment: In my case HX-53 worked without any changes on Wemos Di mini, but angle/range to trigger was very small. I did as advised @MatsK, solder a 100 ohm resistor in parallel to 221. So now I have 68,75 ohm resist on 221, but angle/range almost did not increase. Can I make more lower the resistance on 221 (to 30-40 ohm) to increase transmit power even more?
Sorry what I write this as an answer, I can't comment.

Comment: @Bleach - If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/ask button. Include a link to this answer if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have one just like yours. I was trying to use it on my Arduino to send commands to my AC like a remote but as it turns out, the Vcc pin on the HX-53 breakout board appears to be a dummy and doesn’t connect to anything as far as i know. By right there should be a transistor circuit driving that LED. As it is now, not only is there insufficient current from the signal pin to drive that IR LED for signal bursts, but the red SMD LED in series with the resistor is also stealing some of the current away from the IR LED. In the end, I had to buy a BJT, a standalone IR LED, some resistors and design my own transistor circuit to drive it.

On the transistor’s collector side I had a connection to Vcc and the IR LED in series with a resistor. On the base side was a connection to the signal pin and a resistor. The emitter was connected directly to Ground. Values of the resistors you use will depend largely on the Vcc, the LED max forward current, the specs of the transistor you choose and available current from the power supply.

Hope this helps.